# Associativity of an algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

So, the whole topic is new to me, sorry if I may be unclear with what I want to solve.

Let $\langle F(U),\circ \rangle$ be an algebraic structure with $F = \left\{f \mid  f: U\mapsto U\right\}$. Is the composition associative?

I think yes, the proof of associative composition is quite common but I don't know if it is true in this case with $F$.

Comment: This depends on the algebraic structure. If the law is just composition $f\circ g$, then it is associative. If it is, say, given by $f\cdot g=fg-gf$, then it is not associate in general.

Comment: how do you understand for map-composition?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, composition of functions is always associative.  You can check this directly from the definition: to check that $(f\circ g)\circ h=f\circ(g\circ h)$, you need to check that these two functions agree on any input.  So fix $x\in U$ and compute using the definition of $\circ$: $$((f\circ g)\circ h)(x)=(f\circ g)(h(x))=f(g(h(x)))$$
$$(f\circ(g\circ h))(x)=f((g\circ h)(x))=f(g(h(x)))$$